# Getting error "The getter document isn't defined for the type 'object'"

Tags: flutter

So I'm getting this error:

```
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

then when i add a ? there is a new error:

```
Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'.
```

I've already imported everything I need to idk why this is happening
here is what is wrote:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:messenger_complete_rebuild/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:messenger_complete_rebuild/services/database.dart';
import 'package:messenger_complete_rebuild/views/signin.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isSearching = false;
   late Stream usersStream;

  TextEditingController searchUsernameEditingController =
      TextEditingController();

  onSearchBtnClick() async {
    isSearching = true;
    setState(() {});
    usersStream = await DatabaseMethods()
        .getUserByUserName(searchUsernameEditingController.text);
        setState(() {});
  }

  Widget searchUsersList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: usersStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return Image.network(ds['imgUrl']);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I've been following a tutorial, it's one year old but the only issues so far have been of null safety, so this is weird, I have been following everything exactly, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it
Replaced
`StreamBuilder`
with `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapShot>`
and also added  to `late Stream usersStream` (`late Stream<QuerySnapshot> usersStream`)

Comment: In my case I used as `StreamBuilder<dynamic>` because it was listening Stream Bloc state emit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `snapshot.data!.docs` instead of `snapshot.data.documents`

Comment: nope same error